# How to specify empty list, empty dict and Boolean as a default value for a robot framework keyword.?

Tags: python, robotframework

I want to specify default values like in python

```
def my_function(arg1="my_string", arg2=[], arg3={}, arg4=True):
    pass
```

The following is a sample keyword definition equivalent to above. I want to specify default values.

```
*** Keywords ***
My Function

    [Arguments]     ${ARG1}=my_default_string    ${ARG2}= <How to specify empty list)    ${ARG3}= <How to specify empty dict)    ${ARG4}= <How to specify boolean true)

    some statements
    some more statements
```

Comment: Don't use a mutables (`[]` and `{}` in your case) as default arguments. It will have a weird side effect if you change them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While the given answer is useful, it does not really answer the question, since the question was asking how  to do so in Robot Framework, and not in Python. Here's how you'd do it in Robot Framework:

```
My Function
    [Arguments]    ${arg1}=my_string    ${arg2}=${None}    ${arg3}=${None}    ${arg4}=${True}
```

Notice I used lower case names for your args as well. If you want to follow best practices, you should use upper case variable names for global variables, not for local or argument variable names.

Comment: Thanks, This is what i am looking for...

I used the following code to make it an empty list if None.

${value}=  Run Keyword If  ${value} is ${None}  Create Dictionary
...  ELSE  Set Variable  ${value}

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the comments of your question, you [do not want to use mutable default values](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments). A common idiom in this case is something like so:

```
def my_function(arg1="my_string", arg2=None, arg3=None, arg4=True):
    if arg2 is None:
        arg2 = []
    if arg3 is None:
        arg3 = {}
```

Note that `arg1` and `arg4` were not changed. This is because they are IMMUTABLE, and thus can be used properly as default arguments. Obviously, one issue with this approach is that the user of your function does not easily know what type is expected for `arg2` and `arg3` so you will want to make sure and include a docstring that explains the expected types.

Comment: useful answer that gives valuable information, but note that this doesn't really answer the core question, which was how to define this in Robot Framework.

Comment: Thanks.. I asked, how to define this in Robot framework.? 
But what you explained is new to me.....  
I did this mistake at many places while writing python code.

Answer (score 1):

For empty array, dictionary, etc. use these predefined constants:

```
${EMPTY} # 
@{EMPTY} # = empty array
&{EMPTY} # = empty dictionary
```

[read documentation](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#id789)